# How to divide by the size of a vector in Tensorflow to compute an average loss like MSE?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two float32 vectors and want to compute mean squared error (MSE).

```
yvec = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=(None,))
yhatvec = tf.placeholder("float32", shape=(None,))

mse = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(yhatvec - yvec)) / tf.size(yvec)

compute_mse = lambda vector1, vector2: mse.eval({yhatvec: vector1, yvec: vector2})

compute_mse([0 1 2 3 4], [5 4 3 2 1])
```

but `tf.size` won't return the length of a vector. I got an error:

`Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int32: 'Tensor("Size_24:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)'`

How do I get the length of a vector? In python we use `len(vec)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.size` is fine, but it returns the result as an integer. You need to cast to float before dividing, as explained in the error message

> Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int32

So you could write

```
mse = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(yhatvec - yvec)) / tf.to_float(tf.size(yvec))
```

Or, use `tf.reduce_mean` which computes the mean for you

```
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(yhatvec - yvec))
```

Or, in your specific case, you can also use the predefined loss

```
mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(yvec, yhatvec)
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind explaining the error message TensorFlow complained? I understood this part now: "Tensor conversion requested dtype float32" but not the remaining one.

Comment: You mean, the part with the tensor info? It is just giving some details about the faulty tensor -- in particular its name, which is useful to identify it.